# Is this a closed embedding of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$, $Y$ be two schemes and $f$ be morphism from $Y$ to $X$. Now, consider the corresponding morphism $Y \times_{X} Y$ to $ Y \times Y$. Is this a closed embedding?

Comment: By $Y\times Y$ do you mean $Y\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{Z}} Y$?

Comment: Yes! I mean $Y\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{Z}} Y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is separated over $\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec\ZZ$, then yes.

Proof:
The following is a pullback diagram (see [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec3014public.pdf), pg. 37, Ex 1.3.S):
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y\times_X Y @>>> Y\times_{\Spec\ZZ}Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
X @>>> X\times_{\Spec\ZZ}X\\
\end{CD}
$$
If $X$ is separated over $\Spec\ZZ$, then the bottom morphism is a closed immersion. Then since the [base change of a closed immersion is a closed immersion](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JW), $Y\times_X Y\to Y\times_{\Spec \ZZ}Y$ is a closed immmersion.

Edit: As Marc Paul pointed out below, if $X$ is not separated over $\Spec\ZZ$, then if $Y=X$ and $f=\textrm{id}_X$, then the map $Y\times_X Y\to Y\times_{\Spec\ZZ} Y$ is just the map $X\to X\times_{\Spec\ZZ} X$, which is the diagonal map. By the assumption that $X$ is not separated over $\Spec\ZZ$, this is not a closed embedding.

For more on the general form of the pullback diagram above, see [this nice MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/80812/69100).

**Edit:** in response to the further question below as to whether the map $Y\times_X Y\to Y\times_{\Spec\ZZ} Y$ is always a monomorphism, the answer is yes. In fact to be more precise, the map is always a locally closed immersion.

Proof: The morphism $X\to X\times_{\Spec\ZZ} X$ is always a [locally closed immersion](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IM). For a justification, see [the Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KH). Locally closed immersions are preserved under base change, so $Y\times_X Y\to Y\times_{\Spec\ZZ} Y$ is a locally closed immersion. Finally [immersions are monomorphisms](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L1).

Comment: If $X$ is not separated over $\mathbb Z$, I think you can just take $Y= X$  for a counterexample. Then $Y\times_X Y = X\times_X X = X$, and the morphism we consider is probably just the diagonal map $X\to X\times _\mathbb Z X$?

Comment: @MarcPaul Oh yeah, good point xD I'll edit that in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it true that the map $Y \times_{X} Y$ to $Y \times Y$ a monomorphism?

Comment: @grok Yes, I'll edit an explanation into my answer.